# Creating an object and calling it

Tags: java, oop

this is my current code to store rooms(it compiles fine) but in the UML there is a variable called addEquipment and there is also another class called Equipment to be defined. I'm having trouble wrapping my head around what I'm supposed to do with this. Am I supposed to create and call an object called Equipment? what goes in addEquipment?

```
public class Room {
    //begin variable listing
    private String name;
    private int id;
    private int capacity;
    private String equipmentList;

    //begins get methods for variables  
    public String getName(){ 
        return name;
    }
    public int getID(){ 
        return id;
    }
    public int getCapacity(){
        return capacity;
    }
    public String getEquipmentList(){
        return equipmentList;
    }

    //  Set the variables
    public void setName(String aName){
        name=aName;
    }

    public void setID(int anID){
        id=anID;
    }

    public void setCapacity(int aCapacity){
        capacity=aCapacity; 
    }

    public void setEquipmentList(String anEquipmentList){
        equipmentList=anEquipmentList; 
    }

    public String addEquipment(String newEquipment, String currentEquipment){

    }

    //Create room object
    public Room(int capacity, String equipmentList) {
        setCapacity(capacity);
        setEquipmentList(equipmentList);
    }

    //Convert variables to string version of room
    public String toString(){
        return "Room "+name+", capacity: "+capacity+", equipment: "+getEquipmentList();
    }
}
```

Comment: `addEquipment` would be a *method*, not a variable, just like `setEquipmentList`. This indicates that there is a *list* of equipment (objects) contained in a `Room` to which single pieces of equipment (i.e. objects of type `Equipment`) can be added. Does this help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new class `Equipment` and modify your attribute `equipmentList` to be a `List`:

```
 public class Equipment {
        private String name;

        public Equipment(String name) {
           this.name = name;
        }
}

public class Room {
    //begin variable listing
    private String name;
    private int id;
    private int capacity;
    private List<Equipment> equipmentList = new ArrayList<Equipment>();

    //begins get methods for variables  
    public String getName(){ 
        return name;
    }
    public int getID(){ 
        return id;
    }
    public int getCapacity(){
        return capacity;
    }
    public List<Equipment> getEquipmentList(){
        return equipmentList;
    }

    //  Set the variables
    public void setName(String aName){
        name=aName;
        }

    public void setID(int anID){
        id=anID;
    }

    public void setCapacity(int aCapacity){
            capacity=aCapacity; 
    }

    public void setEquipmentList(List<Equipment> anEquipmentList){
        equipmentList=anEquipmentList; 
    }

    public String addEquipment(String newEquipment, String currentEquipment){
        Equipment oneEquipment = new Equipment(newEquipment);
        equipmentList.add(oneEquipment);
    }

    //Create room object
    public Room() {
        setCapacity(capacity);
        setEquipmentList(equipmentList);
    }

    //Convert variables to string version of room
    public String toString(){
        String capacity=String.valueOf(getCapacity());
        String room = "Room "+name+", capacity: "+capacity+", equipment:     "+getEquipmentList();
        return room;
    }
}
```

In the method `addEquipment`, you can create a new Equipment and add it to `equipmentList`, like code above.

Comment: What's `currentEquipment` for in `addEquipment(String newEquipment, String currentEquipment)`?!

Comment: Thanks! but is there a way to make it an array instead of a list?

Comment: Yes, you *can* use an array. But that's rather complicated because the array would usually have be resized for new items. Use an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) as your `List` and you're good.

Comment: Hanno Binder is right. You have to check the size each time you add an element to the array. ArrayList does it for you.

Comment: (As the name suggests, `ArrayList` is a `List` which privately uses an array behind the scenes; the implementation takes care of managing that array for you, including growing it when needed &c.)

Comment: Sweet Ive changed the set method for equipmentList but its not working

Comment: What "not working" means? Compilation error? How are you calling the method?

Answer (score 0):

An Equipment class could be anything. Lets assume the "Equipment"-class has a String called "name" as it's attribute

```
public class Equipment {
  String name;

  public Equipment( String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return this.name
  }   
}
```

When you extend your Room class by the requested "addEquipment" method, you can do something like this.

```
public class Room {

  ... // Your code

  private int equipmentIndex = 0;
  private Equipment[] equipment = new Equipment[10]; // hold 10 Equipment objects

  public void addEquipment( Equipment eq ) {
    if ( equipmentIndex < 10 ) {
      equipment[ equipmentIndex ] = eq;
      equipmentIndex++;
      System.out.println("Added new equipment: " + eq.getName());
    } else {
      System.out.println("The equipment " + eq.getName() + " was not added (array is full)");
    }
  }
}
```

Now when you call

```
 room.addEquipment( new Equipment("Chair") );
```

on your previously initialized object of the Room-class, you will get

```
 "Added new equipment: Chair"
```

Hope this helps a bit.

PS: The code is untestet (maybe there hides a syntax error somewhere)